# Is there a way to use commands in a list float?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am currently working in a document which has a lot of these kinds of list:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*, font=\bfseries, leftmargin=*]
\item an item
\item another item
\end{emumerate}
```

I have tried to shorten this using the following code:

```
\newcommand{\mc}{label=\Alph*, font=\bfseries, leftmargin=*}

\begin{enumerate}[\mc]
\item an item
\item another item
\end{emumerate}
```

However, this method doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to shorten this command? By the way, I am using the enumitem package

Comment: Are *all* of your list of that kind, or just part of them? If they're all, you can use `\setlist{enumerate }{label....}`, otherwise the correct way is to define your list type with `\newlist`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the parser cannot see the commas when you do it like this.

But `enumitem` has its own buildin system to defining these as new keys, see `\SetEnumitemKey` in the manual, fx

```
\SetEnumitemKey{mc}{label=\Alph*, font=\bfseries, leftmargin=*}
...
\begin{enumerate}{mc}
```

The author promises that they will never define keys that starts with `:` so defining the personal key as `:mc` should be safe from future updates.